# API [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]

Tags: javascript, api

I am trying to connect (Laravel API) with (React native app), I test the API in the postman and it working 100% fine, but when I fetch in the react native app  I got the following error !

**the error**

```
    [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
- node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:527:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:135:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:387:16 in callTimers
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:425:19 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:112:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:373:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

**and in the app, it shows like this:**
[image]

**there is my app.js code(only the fetch function ):**

```
myfun = async()=>{

await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login',{

    method:'POST',
    headers:{
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({"email":email, "password": passowrd})
}).then(res => res.json())
.then(resData =>{
    alert(resData);
    console.log(resData);
});
}
```

Comment: `http://http://`...?

Comment: catch the error.. use try catch inside async or  myfun().catch()

Comment: Typo aside, unless your react-native app is running on the same machine as your API, you won't want to use `127.0.0.1`. You'll need to connect to your server's IP address on whatever network the two devices share

Comment: Check the URL Again it has two http. Also check if the API you are calling is deployed at 127.0.0.1(your local machine)

Comment: Add CORS header in server side API

Comment: Hi ,i fix the two http ,and steel  the same error ,and the ip is my local machine ip where both project works onto!

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit late but to help others:
In your fetch, you must add your IPv4 address (usually starts with 192)

then replace

```
await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login'
```

with

```
await fetch('http://192.xxx.x.xx:8000/api/login'
```

And in laravel, starts your port with the same host (in your terminal):

```
php artisan serve --host 192.xxx.x.xx --port="8000"
```

It worked for me :)

Comment: After deploying to server. Will return the same error or not?